# ¿Como bloquear al usuario los siguientes stepper al crear, pero que al actualizar tenga acceso a los demás? Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hola esoty trabajando con algo parecido a un Stepper, el tema es al crear solo debo permitir que ueda acceder a Datos del proyecto y deba registrarlo, para que despues se redirija la pagina actualizar y me habilite las demás casillas.

**Vista para crear proyecto** => Solo quiero que tenga acceso a Datos del proyecto.
[image: Create]

Mientras que al actualizar tenga acceso a los demás pasos (atributos, configuracion y traduccioones)

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="iq-card">
            <div class="iq-card-body p-0">
                <div class="iq-edit-list">
                    <ul class="iq-edit-profile d-flex nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="col-md-3 p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#project-data">
                                Datos del Proyecto
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3 p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#attributes">
                                Atributos
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3 p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#configure-email">
                                Configuración de Emails
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-md-3 p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#translate-project">
                                Asociar Traducciones
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: puedes crear roles aquie un [ejemplo](https://medium.com/@cvallejo/autenticaci%C3%B3n-y-manejo-de-roles-de-usuarios-en-laravel-7-50aa79fa1bed)

Comment: @Bryro es que ya trabajo con roles, pero el mismo usuario tiene acceso a crear y modificar el proyecto, la idea es que al crear proyecto solo quede habilitada o activada Datos del Proyecto, una vez rellenado se guarda el proyecto y te redirige la pagina actualizar y quiere que hay se habilite las demás casillas

Comment: `if($action == 'add') { /* pestañas desactivadas */ } else { /* pestañas activadas */ }`